# How to get frontend product url when adding new product in admin using catalog_product_save_after event

Tags: magento-1.9

I want product frontend url when admin adding new product. we use `catalog_product_save_after` event in this event we will get all information about product except product url

```
public function addNewproduct($observer) {

        $product = $observer->getEvent()->getProduct();
    $product->getName();
    $product->getShortDescription();
    Mage::getBaseUrl( Mage_Core_Model_Store::URL_TYPE_WEB, true ).$product->getUrlPath();// not get this product url path

}
```

Comment: Can you please show your full code how to get other detaisl

Answer (score 1):

Try this working code :

```
public function addNewproduct($observer) {

    $product = $observer->getEvent()->getProduct();
    $product->getName();
    $product->getShortDescription();
    //Mage::getBaseUrl( Mage_Core_Model_Store::URL_TYPE_WEB, true ).$product->getUrlPath();// not get this product url path
    $suffix = Mage::getStoreConfig('catalog/seo/product_url_suffix');
    $productUrl = Mage::getUrl().$product->getUrlKey().$suffix;

}
```

Comment: But suffix is coming from admin global setting like .html

Comment: @MagikVishal, Now check my updated answer

Comment: We will get storewise product url is  right?

Comment: @MagikVishal, By default product url will same for all store. If you want, you can change the product url key for any store manually. We can get the url key of any store by providing store id.

Comment: @MagikVishal, Is your issue resolved ?